# Plot a histogram grouped by an extra column

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I am having trouble plotting a datafile like this as a grouped histogram.

```
x-axis group y-axis
1 11 0.1123
1 22 0.1687
1 33 0.1312
2 11 0.4567
2 22 0.4578
2 33 0.7465
3 11 0.7532
3 22 0.7742
3 33 0.7123
```

So I would like the histogram to be x-axis against y-axis, but within each x-axis "bin" there are 3 different bars, one for each group, like this image:

[image]

I can get a histogram of x against y using `plot 'file.dat' using 1:3` but can't get it to group by the second column. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I'd do this is to reformat the data in columns like this:

```
x-axis group11 group22 group33
1 0.1123 0.1687 0.1312
2 0.4567 0.4578 0.7465
3 0.7532 0.7742 0.7123
```

Then it's the usual gnuplot histogram.

```
set style fill solid 1.00 border -1
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 2
plot 'data2.dat' using 2 t "11", '' using 3 t "22", '' using 4:xtic(1) t "33"
```

Result looks like this:
[image]

Comment: +1, to rearrange the data you could use an awk script like `awk '{a[$1]=a[$1] FS $3}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' data2.dat`.